# Vercel Really Slow Server Response of Assets

Tags: next.js, google-chrome-devtools, vercel

I built a website with the help of Next.js. The website contains images and videos. The videos are autoplayed which means they are fetched immediately. The website has been deployed on Vercel. I experience big issues with the loading times of all assets not only the videos:

[Chrome Dev Tools showing loading times of assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgS8.png)

It seems like the assets are served one after another and since some of the videos are quite big ~10Mb other resources are blocked for quite a while.

Is it normal that Vercel does only serve one asset at a time? I thought that multiple videos or images could be served simultaneously.

Also, I am wondering why it does take so long in the first place. My internet connection is roughly 100Mbit/s and I do not experience any issues on other websites I have deployed to Vercel. Just this one is incredibly slow and has issues serving the assets.

Does anyone know what's happening?

I already thought the problem was that there were too many and too big videos on the website which is why I reduced the size of each video and added a lazy loading functionality to the videos so they are just loaded when needed. However, this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: It seems Vercel is just a slow hosting service. My total initial download size is 14kb and it takes 4seconds.  The initial html which is 91 B takes 2.5 seconds. Look at the speeds in this post, which the Vercel team locked https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40073